# Yii: Client-side sorting & pagination with CGridView and CArrayDataProvider

Tags: php, yii

Here is the use case I am trying to solve for:

I have an array of data which I am displaying in a grid. I am using CGridView, and am wrapping that array with a CArrayDataProvider.

I am fetching all of the data for the array in one request, and I'd like to do the pagination purely on the client side (with javascript). IE: My if my array has 100 items, I want to display 20 at a time with pagination / sorting - without having to make any additional server requests for the pagination / sorting functions.

After doing a bunch of googling I wasn't able to find a solution that already exists and doesn't require writing my own CSort / CPagination implementations. Does anyone happen to have a solution for this / can point me at something useful?

Comment: Did you try setting the `pagination` property to 20 for the `CArrayDataProvider`? [There's an example in the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider/).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the issue. Setting the amount of items per page isn't the challange. The problem is that the default pagination still relies on making server-side requests to scroll through the pages. IE: The page links will be links to reload the page via the controller with the addition of page/id offsets. That is not the desired behavior. The desired behavior is for the pagination to happen purely in the browser with JavaScript.

Comment: The whole point of a pagination is to avoid large `HTML` pages and long page loads. Even if you don't display everything, refusing `AJAX` calls will dramatically decrease the performance of your site. You can't do this with `Yii` ATM. The closest thing you could do, is to hide/show entries in a `CGridView`based on clicks.

Comment: Pagination has more benefits than just avoiding large chunks of HTML - In my case it's more about providing a better user experience than reducing html document length. I know that the use case I am trying to achieve isn't the "usual" use case, which is why I'm trying to see if anyone else has run into it / solved for it.

Comment: How do you damage the user experience if you send AJAX requests?

Comment: It's just more work to implement... the particular case I am working with is with an analytic product, where the queries can take a long time to return data. It is most efficient to grab the whole result set at once and have the front end manage the pagination/sorting/etc. It could be implemented with AJAX but would take more work because now I'd have to implement a cache for the result set first and have the AJAX back-end run from the cached set. Was hoping to find a quick and dirty way to just have it happen in the browser.

Comment: have you tried any jquery plugins?

Comment: I've used the datatables JQuery plugin for other projects, which I know could satisfy the requirements for this use case, but I also don't really want to introduce JQueryUI to this project - would rather keep the look and feel consistent since I use the CGridView throughout the site.

Comment: as ors has already said, not possible with cgridview atm.